# windows service timer set to weekly

Tags: c#, service, timer

I have a windows service running with several timed functions:

```
   _timer = new Timer(1 * 60 * 1000); // every 1 minute
   _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
   _timer.Start();
   _fbtimer = new System.Timers.Timer(48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   _fbtimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fbtimer_Elapsed);
   _fbtimer.Start();
   //Weekley Snapshot
   _ventimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2 * 60 * 1000);
   _ventimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ventimer_Elapsed);
   _ventimer.Start();
   //Weekly Activity
   _tevtimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2 * 60 * 1000);
   _tevtimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tevtimer_Elapsed);
   _tevtimer.Start();
```

How do i set the timer to occur say once a week, or even better set it to a specific time on one day a week, without using quatrz/windows scheduler or a too different method.

Addition: this is how i am running a task everyday at 10

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //log.Info("Info - Check time");
    DateTime startAt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10);
    if (_lastRun < startAt && DateTime.Now >= startAt)
    {
      _timer.Stop();
      //Stuff
      _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
      _timer.Start();
     }
}
```

Comment: " without using quatrz/windows scheduler ". **Bad idea.**

Comment: ok any suggestions best/simple way to implement quartz in this method because i have tried before no luck

Comment: If you change `AddHours(10)` to `AddDays(7)` you have the answer to your own question.

Comment: ok thanks assuming I add 7 days and 10 hours and start the service on a monday it will run 10 clock every monday

Comment: Yes. I personally would define a variable `nextRun` instead of `lastRun`, so you can specify to the second when the next run should occur, independent of when you start the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without using quatrz/windows scheduler or a too different method.

Why reinvent the wheel, poorly? Anyway a weekly timer won't do much good. What if you code the timer to wait a week, and the machine reboots halfway the week for updates? The timer will start waiting a week again.

You'd better let it run at a small interval and check each time whether it's time to run the method you want. This way you can pre-calculate the 'event time' and check for it each time.

Comment: The reason is i have tried implementing quartz once and didn't find it straight forward. maybe you could then tell me the best way and what to do please? i tried following tutorial on the site

Comment: @Beginner I think CodeCaster means that you set, let's say, an hourly timer which checks a DateTime variable storing the next date and time that the routine should run. If the date and time are in the past, run the method and update the DateTime variable for the next run.

Comment: Sort of like i am doing in my first timer? please see addition added to question

Comment: @Beginner Yes, see my additional comment there.