# How to run an insert method weekly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, informix

I have an SQL Server stored procedure which returns a table result. I want to insert the result into an Informix table to push notifications weekly (once per week) for my employees.

My questions are:

- Is the Windows service the best solution for this scenario or is there something better than that?
- How to run a method like this weekly?

Comment: you can use sql server jobs

Comment: @SainPradeep : the `sql server procedure` just return results , after that i need to insert the result in `informix table` and where 's the problem .

Answer (score 1):

here you have windows service and sql server agent as an option..
It depends on what you want to accomplish. Do you want to store the deleted archives somewhere? Log the changes? An SQL Job should perform better since it is run directly in the database, but it is easier to give a service acces to resources outside the database. So it depends on what you want to do,,

for windows service you can follow..
[windows service timer set to weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953785/windows-service-timer-set-to-weekly)

and for sql server agent..

Expand SQL Server Agent, expand Jobs, right-click the job that you want to schedule, and click Properties. Select the Schedules page, and then click Pick. Select the schedule that you want to attach, and then click OK. In the Job Properties dialog box, double-click the attached schedule

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a Windows Service is a good solution that provides flexibility and space for future change. Using the Agent tightly couples you to SQL Server which may not be desirable in the long run. Also the kind of activities and capabilities offered on SQL server are limited unless you start using SQL CLR and still there are limitations to that.

You could combine the Windows Service with a Scheduled Job that starts the Windows Service close to the Timer date then stops it and so on, in a poor man's way of trying to save compute resources. The advantage of using the Scheduled job is that it allows you to control timing without recompiling your windows service, or changing the config files of the Windows Service.